# How can we express value of cosine similarity of two documents into percentage?

Tags: matching, data-mining

We were doing project work for plagiarism checking. For this purpose, we have taken a term frequency vector of two documents and measured the similarity using a cosine similarity measure. The value of cosine similarity is limited between 0 and 1. We know that the value of cosine similarity will be 1 if two documents exactly match with one another. In this case, we can say 100% match. Moreover, the value will be 0 for no match i.e. 0 % match. Furthermore, if the value is 0.65, then how do we find the percentage from this score? The definition and formula of cosine similarity are shown in the following figure.
[image: Fig. Cosine Similarity Calculation]

Comment: Don't use an image of text or mathematics.  This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Also, we require you to provide proper attribution for the source of that material.

Comment: Beware that a cosine can be negative (revealing *anticorrelation*). Depending on your application, negative values should be taken for zero, or in absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your two vectors $x,y$ belong to $\{\pm1\}^n$. The formula of cosine similarity in this case gives the cosine similarity as
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i = \frac{\#\{i : x_i = y_i\} - \#\{i : x_i \neq y_i\}}{n} = 1 - 2\Pr_i[x_i \neq y_i] = 2\Pr_i[x_i=y_i] - 1.
$$
As can be seen, the range of cosine similarity is actually $[-1,1]$.

Sometimes other proxies of cosine similarity are used. For example, cosine distance is one minus cosine similarity; this ranges over $[0,2]$. Similarly, "half cosine distance" is half the cosine distance, which ranges over $[0,1]$. In the case above, half cosine distance is exactly $\Pr_i[x_i \neq y_i]$.

Starting with the actual cosine similarity $S$, you can extract $\Pr_i[x_i = y_i]$ as $\frac{1+S}{2}$. In the case of two vectors $x,y \in \{\pm 1\}^n$, this is the percentage of indices in which $x_i$ equals $y_i$. For general vectors $x,y$, the quantity $\frac{1+S}{2}$ no longer has this interpretation. It is just a distance measure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and nice explanation. But I am going the use the above formula shown in the edited question. Can you please reply in this regard?

Comment: That’s also the formula I use.

Comment: A different interpretation of the question: what does a cosine similarity of 0.65 tell you?  Using unit, but real-valued, vectors $x$ and $y$, and the https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product, you see that the $x$ and $y$ vectors make an angle with cosine of 0.65.  So that's some angle (about 49 degrees).  So it all depends on what $x$ and $y$ are representing, are they continuous or discrete for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_{ij}$ is number of times that word $j$ appears in document $i$. Then the *cosine similarity* between document $A$ and document $B$ is the normalised dot product:

$$\mathit{sim}(A,B) = \frac{\sum_j x_{Aj} x_{Bj}}{\sqrt{\left(\sum_j x_{Aj}^2\right) \left(\sum_j x_{Bj}^2\right)}}$$

This is normalised to be between $0$ and $1$, as you rightly said. Because the components of the vectors are word counts, there are no negative numbers here.

By the way, on natural language texts, the cosine measure is not considered to be a good measure because it weighs extremely common words (e.g. "the", "and", "but") more highly. One option is to drop these words (called "stop words"), but then you'd better hope that the document isn't about [The Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Who).

The other option is to use a measure which estimates the information content of each word, such as measures based on [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). Other options include a $\chi^2$ test.

You could, if you wanted to, interpret this as a percentage just by multiplying it by 100, or perhaps using $\frac{200}{\pi}\arcsin\left( \mathit{sim}(A,B) \right)$, but it doesn't really have a natural interpretation as a percentage. A percentage is a *proportion* or a *probability*, but cosine similarity is an *angle*.

You occasionally hear percentages like this thrown around, such as that humans and chimpanzees share 98.8% of our DNA, but it's always far from obvious exactly what that measures and whether or not it makes sense to interpret it as a percentage.

Finally, it's not clear to me that a measure based on treating the document as a "bag of words" is a good way to detect plagiarism in the first place. An author often uses a similar vocabulary in a lot of their works, but for detecting *copying*, surely the order in which the words appear makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the cosine by one hundred.